# Error occured while using fread function in R

Tags: r, fread

I am trying to read a csv file with delimited with | using fread() in R.But i am getting bellow error.

I am using query like :-

```
fread("\\Path\\file_name.csv",sep="|") 



 Expecting 23 cols, but line 3747410 contains text after processing all cols. It is very likely that this is due to one or more fields having embedded sep='|' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes. fread cannot handle such ambiguous cases and those lines may not have been read in as expected. Please read the section on quotes in ?fread.
In addition: Warning message:
In fread("Path\\File_name.csv",sep="|") :
  Bumped column 5 to type character on data row 3422329, field contains 'NULL'. Coercing previously read values in this column from logical, integer or numeric back to character which may not be lossless; e.g., if '00' and '000' occurred before they will now be just '0', and there may be inconsistencies with treatment of ',,' and ',NA,' too (if they occurred in this column before the bump). If this matters please rerun and set 'colClasses' to 'character' for this column. Please note that column type detection uses the first 5 rows, the middle 5 rows and the last 5 rows, so hopefully this message should be very rare. If reporting to datatable-help, please rerun and include the output from verbose=TRUE.
```

Help me for solving this issue...Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: so how can i handle this issue in fread() function, i also checked sep="auto" and sep2="auto" but it gives same error

Comment: check rows 3747410 and 3422329 in your csv. Looks like there's a problem with your csv

Comment: how can i check in file where the issue is,because my file is very large

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626637/reading-a-text-file-in-r-line-by-line, read line by line, check the problem with | in one column

Comment: Thanks M.siwick for giving above reference

Comment: It's very useful for me,but in my data shows on of the column contains multiple space like in id variable |451256312       451266521|

Comment: so error occurs because of that or any other issue

Comment: can we give a row range in fread() function for checking line number 3747410

Comment: I tried read.delim2() and it works properly for my data sets.. data.table(read.delim2("Path\\File_name",sep="|",quote = ""))