# fread to read top n rows from a large file

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am getting below error when reading first n rows from a big file(around 50 GB) using `fread`. Looks like a memory issue. I tried to use `nrows=1000` . But no luck. Using linux

```
file ok but could not memory map it. This is a 64bit process. There is probably not enough contiguous virtual memory available.
```

Can this below code be replaced with `read.csv` with all options as used below? Does it help?

```
  rdata<- fread(
      file=csvfile, sep= "|", header=FALSE, col.names= colsinfile,
    select= colstoselect, key = "keycolname", na.strings= c("", "NA")
    , nrows= 500
  )
```

Comment: What if you replace `csvfile` with `paste('head -n 500', csvfile)`?

Comment: @mt1022 : got an error `File 'head -n 500 /csvfile' doesnt exist`

Comment: The argument should finally looks like `input = "head -n 500 /path/to/csvfile"`. Please use the `input` argument rather than `file` argument to allow shell commands. I do not have a file that large to test. I hope this works.

Comment: @mt1022 : thats awsome. when used with `input` it works!.. You should put this as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another workaround is to fetch the first 500 lines with shell command:

```
rdata<- fread(
    cmd = paste('head -n 500', csvfile),
    sep= "|", header=FALSE, col.names= colsinfile,
    select= colstoselect, key = "keycolname", na.strings= c("", "NA")
)
```

I don't known why `nrows` doesn't work, though.

Comment: Newer versions (somewhere between 3.4.0 and 3.6.0) recommend `cmd =` instead of `input =`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would help you:

```
processFile = function(filepath) {
con = file(filepath, "r")
while ( TRUE ) {
line = readLines(con, n = 1)
if ( length(line) == 0 ) {
  break
}
print(line)
}
close(con)
}
```

see [reading a text file in R line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626637/reading-a-text-file-in-r-line-by-line)..
In your case you'd probably want to replace the `while ( TRUE )` by `for(i in 1:1000)`