# R: Split multiple rows into a list element based on pattern

Tags: r, parsing

I'm trying to parse this .txt file in R: https://ftp.expasy.org/databases/cellosaurus/cellosaurus.txt

It's essentially a single column data frame of some ~2 million rows, with each entity being described by multiple rows and bookended by rows containing the string "//".

Ideally, I could capture each entity, made up of multiple rows, as a list element by splitting at "//", but I'm not sure of the most efficient way to go about this.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's a snippet of what I'm working with:

```r
[87] "//"                                                                                                                                                                                             
 [88] "ID   #40a"                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [89] "AC   CVCL_IW91"                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [90] "DR   Wikidata; Q54422071"                                                                                                                                                                       
 [91] "RX   PubMed=28159921;"                                                                                                                                                                          
 [92] "CC   Characteristics: Established from parent cell line after two passages in the peritoneal cavity of C57BL/6 mice (PubMed=28159921)."                                                         
 [93] "CC   Transformant: ChEBI; CHEBI:46666; Crocidolite asbestos."                                                                                                                                   
 [94] "CC   Derived from metastatic site: Peritoneum."                                                                                                                                                 
 [95] "CC   Breed/subspecies: C57BL/6."                                                                                                                                                                
 [96] "DI   NCIt; C21619; Mouse mesothelioma"                                                                                                                                                          
 [97] "OX   NCBI_TaxID=10090; ! Mus musculus"                                                                                                                                                          
 [98] "HI   CVCL_IW90 ! 40"                                                                                                                                                                            
 [99] "SX   Male"                                                                                                                                                                                      
[100] "AG   1-2M"                                                                                                                                                                                      
[101] "CA   Cancer cell line"                                                                                                                                                                          
[102] "DT   Created: 15-05-17; Last updated: 02-07-20; Version: 3"                                                                                                                                     
[103] "//"                                                                                                                                                                                             
[104] "ID   #490"                                                                                                                                                                                      
[105] "AC   CVCL_B375"                                                                                                                                                                                 
[106] "SY   490; Mab 7; Mab7"                                                                                                                                                                          
[107] "DR   CLO; CLO_0001018"                                                                                                                                                                          
[108] "DR   ATCC; HB-12029"                                                                                                                                                                            
[109] "DR   Wikidata; Q54422073"                                                                                                                                                                       
[110] "RX   Patent=US5616470;"                                                                                                                                                                         
[111] "CC   Monoclonal antibody isotype: IgM, kappa."                                                                                                                                                  
[112] "CC   Monoclonal antibody target: Cronartium ribicola antigens."                                                                                                                                 
[113] "OX   NCBI_TaxID=10090; ! Mus musculus"                                                                                                                                                          
[114] "HI   CVCL_4032 ! P3X63Ag8.653"                                                                                                                                                                  
[115] "CA   Hybridoma"                                                                                                                                                                                 
[116] "DT   Created: 06-06-12; Last updated: 12-03-20; Version: 6"                                                                                                                                     
[117] "//"                                                                                                                                                                                             
[118] "ID   #822"                                                                                                                                                                                      
[119] "AC   CVCL_X345"                                                                                                                                                                                 
[120] "SY   822; Mab 13; Mab13"                                                                                                                                                                        
[121] "DR   ATCC; HB-12030"                                                                                                                                                                            
[122] "DR   Wikidata; Q54422076"                                                                                                                                                                       
[123] "RX   Patent=US5616470;"                                                                                                                                                                         
[124] "CC   Monoclonal antibody isotype: IgM, kappa."                                                                                                                                                  
[125] "CC   Monoclonal antibody target: Cronartium ribicola antigens."                                                                                                                                 
[126] "OX   NCBI_TaxID=10090; ! Mus musculus"                                                                                                                                                          
[127] "HI   CVCL_4032 ! P3X63Ag8.653"                                                                                                                                                                  
[128] "CA   Hybridoma"                                                                                                                                                                                 
[129] "DT   Created: 17-07-14; Last updated: 12-03-20; Version: 5"                                                                                                                                     
[130] "//"
```

As an added clarification, my goal is to search for a given accession (AC), e.g. CVCL_X345, and then extract age (AG) and sex (SX) for that accession if they are available.

Comment: Maybe you should provide us a few rows of this data. ]frame so we can understand the pattern.

Comment: Done -- thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: do you have the file in your PC or are you reading directly from the site?

Comment: I have a file saved locally that I'm reading in.

Comment: Sorry, had another  question opened which was  tagged with python.

Comment: It  looks like `readLines(...)` is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626637/read-a-text-file-in-r-line-by-line

Comment: Right, I am using that to get the data into R. I'm wondering about an efficient way to group entities by splitting on a character from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution using `data.table`.

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("https://ftp.expasy.org/databases/cellosaurus/cellosaurus.txt", 
            skip=54, header=FALSE, sep='')
dt[, c("code", "content"):=tstrsplit(sub(" +", "@/@", V1), "@/@") ][, 
  `:=` (V1=NULL, ID=cumsum(code=="//")+1)]
dt <- dt[code!="//"]
dt[dt[content=="CVCL_IW91"], on="ID"][code %chin% c("SX", "AG")]
#>    code content ID i.code i.content
#> 1:   SX    Male  3     AC CVCL_IW91
#> 2:   AG    1-2M  3     AC CVCL_IW91

# or get all of them:
dcast(dt[code %in% c("SX", "AG", "AC")][, .(code, content), by=ID], ID ~ ...,
      value.var="content")
#>             ID        AC              AG     SX
#>      1:      1 CVCL_E548 Age unspecified Female
#>      2:      2 CVCL_KA96            <NA>   <NA>
#>      3:      3 CVCL_IW91            1-2M   Male
#>      4:      4 CVCL_B375            <NA>   <NA>
#>      5:      5 CVCL_X345            <NA>   <NA>
#>     ---                                        
#> 128802: 128802 CVCL_A6IX             29Y   Male
#> 128803: 128803 CVCL_ZB29             57Y Female
#> 128804: 128804 CVCL_ZB30             32Y Female
#> 128805: 128805 CVCL_A3ZF             26Y Female
#> 128806: 128806 CVCL_3449            <NA>   Male
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**Edit**: Brief explanation:

In essence, I want to split each row on the first blank(s) first. I achieve this by replacing these with a separator that does not exist in the entire text (previously checked with `grep`), then use `tstrsplit` to split the first column `V1` based on this separator into two (`code` and `content`). Then I remove `V1` and use `cumsum` to increase the identifier `ID` based on the occurrence of the separator lines (`//`) to label each record with its own identifier.

Comment: This is so great - thank you! Any chance you could break down what's going on in the third line?

Comment: Thanks. See edited answer for a brief explanation.